# Problems in generating HTML with JasperReports

Tags: html, css, pagination, jasper-reports

I am using jasper report with my application and generating the reports in pdf formats, which are coming up fine. We want the user to be able to view those reports in html also with in the application, but generating HTML from jasper contains inline CSS for its individual element which we do not want. (We want to apply our own CSS so that look and feel of application remains same.). If any body has any ideas how it can be done, please help.

Also we do not want large number of  records in a single page in html, so any ideas on how we can implement pagination in such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can separate the CSSs from the HTML which is generated by the iReport.
To check for some more options please open the export options which are under
Tools->> Options ->> Export Options.